# .NET 4.8 Web App using lots of memory but not in the heap?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, memory

I have a .NET 4.8 web app which is using about 680MB of private memory at startup on my dev machine.  It uses about double that on the production server, although the previous production server was closer to what my dev machine is doing.  If I use Diagnostic Tools, it is showing me that the heap is only about 90MB.  I know that there is always some unmanaged memory usage and things like assemblies take up memory, but I can't imagine that is nearly 700MB, and I don't understand why the new production server uses so much more.

Any advice for how to get to the bottom of it?